# Android connection detection not working in Android Studio 2.2.1. What has gone wrong?

Tags: android, android-studio, internet-connection, android-internet

Earlier I used to verify Internet connection and display data accordingly. If it is connected to Internet I used to load data from server and if there is no Internet connection, I used to load offline data. But from Android Studio 2.2.1, however this seems not to be working. The code I used was:

```
 import android.app.Service;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

Context context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

     public boolean isConnected(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)      context.getSystemService(Service.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if(connectivity!=null){
        NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(info!=null){
            if(info.getState()== NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
                return  true;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

I would create new object of this class  :

```
   cd = new ConnectionDetector(this);
```

and then use:

```
  if(cd.isConnected()){
  -----------
  ---------
  }else {
  ------
  ---
  }
```

But this is not working in 2.2.1
What changes are needed to make it work in 2.2.1 ?
I am not a programming expert.

Comment: Hope you have added permissions in Manifest File.

Comment: Yes, added manifest. I think something in the 2.2.1 version. Now Android Studio has given new update 2.2.2 . I think they fix it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Use this for device is connected OR Not.

```
 public class ConnectivityDetector {
    public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
        }
        return false;
    }}
```

You Can check it like this :

```
if (ConnectivityDetector.isConnectingToInternet(ChangePasswordActivity.this)) {
                //Your Code when connected.
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please check your Internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```